# Asking rust to wait for user input from shell script

Tags: rust

I'm learning a bit of rust and in the process automating some internal work.

I currently have a pretty simple shell script:

```bash
read -p 'Hello this is a var ' myvar
echo "---- second"
echo "output: $myvar"
```

In rust, i'm calling this:

```rust
fn main() {

    let mut output = Command::
        new("/bin/bash")
        .arg("./myscript.sh")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
}
```

But i have no idea how to make rust pipe out the `read` prompt and wait for the response from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output), it

> Executes the command as a child process, waiting for it to finish and collecting all of its output.

I.e. it does exactly what you want.

```rust
fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .arg("./myscript.sh")
        .output()
        .unwrap();
}
```

Judging from your naming I've removed the calls to `stdout` and `stderr` since the name `output` seems to suggest you want to store and possibly process the text `myscript.sh` outputs. Also removed the `stdin` call since you want to "pipe out the `read` prompt" which actually doesn't require any piping but can be accomplished by inheriting the `stdin` instead, which is the default behavior.

If you want the output to go to the standard out and error you can [`wait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) on the `Child` returned by `spawn`, don't add any calls to `stdout` or `stderr` either since inheriting the streams is what you want and the default behavior:

```rust
fn main() {
    let exit_status = Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .arg("./myscript.sh")
        .spawn()
        .unwrap()
        .wait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response... So totally new here so forgive me if this is dumb. I actually want to pipe all the output from the script to the console (every echo printf etc). I also have a `read -p` which because it's mix of input output, it doesn't seem to get piped correctly?. Finally, i honestly don't know what to do with the `output` variable... How do i get it to print out? Because i was using spawn, i was using a loop to iterate over th eoutput but that seems wrong.

Comment: In that case you want to just `.spawn().unwrap().wait()`, no `std*` calls as you don't want piping at all, just inheriting the standard streams.

Comment: Excellent! This was perfect! Thank you so much! Rust is a pretty complex language so a lot of this details are hard to just understand form the docs.